# What is the best way to simulate no Internet connection within a Cucumber test?

Tags: ruby, command-line, cucumber, integration-testing

Part of my command-line Ruby program involves checking if there is an internet connection before any commands are processed. The actual check in the program is trivial (using Socket::TCPSocket), but I'm trying to test this behaviour in Cucumber for an integration test.

**The code:**

```
def self.has_internet?(force = nil)
  if !force.nil? then return force
  begin
    TCPSocket.new('www.yelp.co.uk', 80)
    return true
  rescue SocketError
    return false
  end
end

if has_internet? == false
  puts("Could not connect to the Internet!")
  exit 2
end
```

**The feature:**

```
Scenario: Failing to log in due to no Internet connection
  Given the Internet is down
  When I run `login <email_address> <password>`
  Then the exit status should be 2
  And the output should contain "Could not connect to the Internet!"
```

I obviously don't want to change the implementation to fit the test, and I require all my scenarios to pass. Clearly if there is actually no connection, the test passes as it is, but my other tests fail as they require a connection.

**My question: How can I test for this in a valid way and have all my tests pass?**

Answer (score 4):

You can stub your `has_internet?` method and return false in the implementation of the `Given the Internet is down` step.

```
YourClass.stub!(:has_internet?).and_return(false)
```

Comment: This didn't work as the test tried to stub the method, but it hadn't been created yet (inside the command line script), and I couldn't find any other way of doing it, other than an 'aggressive' stub where I edit the function at runtime to always return false in a `Before` hook and then change it back in an `After` hook.

Answer (score 1):

There are three alternative solutions I can think of:

1. have the test temporarily monkeypatch `TCPSocket.initialize` (or *maybe* `Socket#connect`, if that's where it ends up) to pretend the internet is down.
2. write (suid) a script that adds/removes an `iptables` firewall rule to disable the internet, and have your test call the script
3. use `LD_PRELOAD` on a specially written .so shared library that overrides the `connect` C call.  This is harder.

Myself, I would probably try option 1, give up after about 5 minutes and go with option 2.

Comment: Interesting answers, but probably a little overkill - although I did get the idea for "stubbing" the function at runtime through test hooks from number 1, so thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Better check option here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454767/14907

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late for you :), but have a look at

https://github.com/mmolhoek/vcr-uri-catcher

I made this to test network failures, so this should do the trick for you.